# Why am i getting a missing 1 required positional argument: 'connectionList' error but can print connectionList?

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror

could you please explain why connectionList doesn't seems to get passed to the connectionMaker method ?

```
Output of the print : 
[('tFrictionpushButton', 'None', 'clicked', 'open_tFriction'), 
('tGravitypushButton', 'None', 'clicked', 'open_tGravity'), 
('pushButton_connect', 'None', 'clicked', 'pressConnectButton'), 
('lineEdit_address', 'None', 'textChanged', 'saveConnectionConfig')]


code :
def descriptorConnections(self, aliasList, connectionList):
    print(connectionList)
    AutoConnects.connectionMaker(connectionList)
```

Comment: `connectionMaker` expects another argument, probably `self`.  Did you forget to create an `AutoConnects` instance?  Try `AutoConnects().connectionMaker(connectionList)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as the error says, `connectionMaker` is missing an argument.  Its `connectionList` is the *second* argument that it's expecting, and you only provided the first argument.

Since you didn't provide the definition of `AutoConnects.connectionMaker`, I have to guess, but I'm *guessing* that the expected first argument is a `self` instance.  If that's the case, you should be able to fix it by doing:

```
AutoConnects().connectionMaker(connectionList)
```

Or maybe in your own class's `__init__` you want to create a single `AutoConnects` instance:

```
self.connects = AutoConnects()
```

and then in your other methods you can refer to that instance:

```
self.connects.connectionMaker(connectionList)
```